# Powershell Plus or Minus Comparison Operator (Fuzzy Logic)?

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware

So let me tell you what I'm trying to do here. Our SolarWinds alerts report on disk capacity as read by Windows, not the Virtual Machine vDisk size setting. What I'm trying to do is match the size so that I can find the correct vDisk and report on its datastore free space to determine whether or not we can add more.

Here's the problem, the GB number never matches between Windows and VMWare. Say the disk has a 149.67 capacity as reported by Windows, well the VMWare setting is 150, or 150.18854, or anything of that sort. I cannot find the vdisk without knowing the exact number, but theoretically I could find it if I could just say, have a comparison operator that had some breathing room, like plus or minus 1 or even 0.5. So for example:

```
Get-HardDisk -Vm SERVERNAME | Where-Object {
    $_.CapacityGB -lt $size + 0.5 -and
    $_.CapacityGB -gt $size - 0.5
}
```

This doesn't work though, for whatever reason. I need something similar to this. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Turns out to be user error, I was experimenting with the wrong number when testing the command. I thought it was the syntax, it was the number I was using itself.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What are the values and types of `$_.CapacityGB` and `$size`?

Comment: I'd try `Get-HardDisk -Vm SERVERNAME | Where-Object {[math]::Abs($_.CapacityGB - $size) -lt 0.5}` If the difference of both values independent of the sign is less than 0.5 should do.

Comment: have you tried calculating a range and then testing for `-in $SizeRange`? also, what is the object type in `$_.CapacityGB`? i suspect it may be a numeric string instead of a number ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Interesting idea, while I finally got it to work I think i wanna try the range idea which sounds simpler.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'll define it as user error in this case. Once I finish my script I'll just answer my own question and post what I did.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle - the `-in` & --contains` array operators are really quite nice. [*grin*] ///// if you get a chance, please add a note to your OP about the "user error"  mentioned in your reply to AnsgarWiechers - i am quite curious ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

So because I managed to answer my own question I thought I'd post a script for achieving this here. Note that you will need to have a txt file with a comma separated servername and capacity. You could probably modify this to do many other things with VMWare data gathering if you wanted. In the end you'll need to know which columns are which and import to Excel as comma delimited.

Most the variables are decimal values.

Also note that I have no yet figured out a way to programatically deal with the discovery of multiple matching disks.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content "./ServerList.txt"
$logfile = "./Stores.txt"
remove-item "./Stores.txt"

Function LogWrite {
    Param (
    [string]$srv,
    [string]$disk,
    [string]$store
    )
    Add-Content $logfile -value $srv","$disk","$store
}
foreach ($item in $serverlist){
    $store = "Blank"
    $disk = "Blank"
    try {
        $server,$arg = $item.split(',')
        $round = [math]::Round($arg,0)
        $disk = get-harddisk -vm $server | where-object{$_.CapacityGB -lt ($round + 2) -and $_.CapacityGB -gt ($round - 2) }
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($disk)){
            $disk = "Problem locating disk."
            $store = "N/A"
            continue
        }
        if ($disk.count -gt 1) {
            $disk = "More than one matching disk."
            $store = "N/A"
        } else {
            $store = get-harddisk -vm $server | where-object{$_.CapacityGB -lt ($round + 2) -and $_.CapacityGB -gt ($round - 2) } | Get-Datastore | %{ "{0},{1},{2}" -f $_.Name,[math]::Round($_.FreeSpaceGB,1),[math]::Round($_.CapacityGB,1) }
        }
    }
    catch {
        $disk = "Physical"
        $store = "N/A"
    }
    LogWrite $server $disk $store
}
```